# Showing or refuting that $\mathrm{e}^{z}$ is a infra-exponential type function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Hell. I found myself reading the book analytic partial differential equations by Treves  to understand what the operators of the $e^{\partial_z}$ form are like and a doubt arose regarding its symbol (seen as a hyperdifferential operator).

**Definition**. An entire function $F:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is said to be infra-exponential type if to every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $C_{\epsilon}$ such that
\begin{align}
\forall z\in\mathbb{C},\, |F(z)|\leq C_{\epsilon}\mathrm{e}^{\epsilon|z|}
\end{align}

**Question 1**. Is $F(z)=\mathrm{e}^{z}$ infra-exponential type?

**My attempt**: For $\epsilon\geq 1,\, |\mathrm{e}^{z}|\leq \mathrm{e}^{\epsilon |z|}$ with $C_{\epsilon}=1$. But for $0<e<1$ does the inequality still hold?

Comment: No, the inequality doesn't hold if $0<\epsilon<1$, since whatever you take $C_\epsilon$ to be, it will fail with sufficiently large positive real $z$.  So, $e^z$ is not of infra-exponential type.